# Calabash ios hybrid element not found

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I am having a native app with a HTML content on a page.I am not able to inspect the elements in the HTML content of the iOS app.i have tried the following:

query("webView css:'*'")

query("WKwebView css:'*'")

query("UIwebView css:'*'")

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your queries.

```
 query("UIWebView css:'*'")
 query("WKWebView css:'*'")
```

See these documents for examples:

- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support
- https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app/tree/master/CalWebViewApp/features

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It was type error when I submitted the query.I have tried in proper format as provided still empty class is retrieved.Is there any other way to inspect.I am able to retrieve the same content on Android app with query("Webview css:'*')